# Analyzer for search engine in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to implement something like the "apple" example mentioned in the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-index-search-time.html. What type of analyzer do I use, also is there any specific tokenizer, and filters i put in place.
I have tried the below

```
PUT  /search_v5/
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
        "routing": {
          "allocation": {
            "include": {
              "_tier_preference": "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "indexing": {
          "slowlog": {
            "threshold": {
              "index": {
                "debug": "2s"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "max_ngram_diff" : "15",
        "analysis": {
         "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 15
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [

            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
        }
        }},
        "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "g_volume": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
 
        "search_name":{"type" :"keyword"},
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "autocomplete": {
              "type": "text",
              "norms": false,
              "analyzer": "autocomplete",
              "search_analyzer": "autocomplete"
            },
            "search": {
              "type": "text",
              "norms": false,
              "analyzer": "autocomplete",
              "search_analyzer": "autocomplete"
            }
          }
        },
        "name_similar": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "name_simillar": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "autocomplete": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "autocomplete",
              "search_analyzer": "autocomplete",
              "similarity": "boolean"
            },
            "search": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "autocomplete",
              "search_analyzer": "autocomplete",
              "similarity": "boolean"
            }
          }
        },

    
        
      }
    }
  }
```

issue with my search is that when I run the search query with the letter "i" i am looking at only data that starts with the letter "i" but my search results does not work this way. any help will be appreciated.

search query

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"should":[{"match":{"name.autocomplete": {"operator":"and","query":"i","boost":1.0}}},{"match":{"name.search":{"operator":"or","query":"i","boost":0.0}}}]}}]}},"size":10}
```

Comment: show your query to search.

Answer (score 0):

> i am looking at only data that starts with the letter "i"

If you want to search your data only starting with "i" you can use [edge_ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html).

Here is an example:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST my-index-000001/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "2 Quick Foxes."
}
```

edge_ngram tokenizer example OUTPUT:

```
[ Qu, Qui, Quic, Quick, Fo, Fox, Foxe, Foxes ]
```

---

[ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) example:

```
POST _analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "edge_ngram",
  "text": "Quick Fox"
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[ Q, Qu, u, ui, i, ic, c, ck, k, "k ", " ", " F", F, Fo, o, ox, x ]
```

**

> Additional notes: You don't need to use both the index time analyzer
> and search time analyzer. The index time analyzer will be enough for
> your case. Please check the edge_ngram tokenizer example.

**

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, if i were to use edge ngram tokenizer, if my search text was fox, that too would show, right? What if I don't want that but only show autocomplete words, for example if i type "quick fo" then it should show me "quick fox" but if i type "fox" then should say no result found

Comment: That's correct. Please test it you will see the results. 

For your "quick fo" question, you can use the `keyword` field type and regex query.

Comment: thanks for that, can you please elaborate on the "For your "quick fo" question, you can use the keyword field type and regex query" part I am not sure what you mean here.

Comment: Here are some examples for you:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-multi-field

Comment: any update for this?

Comment: sorry i no longer work on this project, so cannot confirm the solution

Comment: I'm not expecting to confirm or do anything from you. :) I just hope it helps the community and you.